# FileReader not working in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filereader

I'm trying to upload an image using `FileReader`, It works fine in debug mode (when set breakpoint on the line `this.name = Image.files[0].name;`), but doesn't work if I deactivate breakpoint. `testDetails.image` gets set to empty string. I have tried `setTimeout` also, its also not working.

```
var fileByteArray = '';
const Image = this.AccUserImage.nativeElement;

if (Image.files && Image.files[0]) {
    this.AccUserImageFile = Image.files[0];
}


var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function (event) {
    var imageData = fileReader.result;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(imageData);
    //for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        fileByteArray += (String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]));
    }
};
if (fileReader && Image.files && Image.files.length) {
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(Image.files[0]);
    }
}

this.name = Image.files[0].name;
const ImageFile: File = this.AccUserImageFile;

let length = this.form.value.addresses.length;
this.testList = [];
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let testDetails = new testDto();
    testDetails.image = btoa(fileByteArray);
}
```

Comment: didn't get you.

Comment: how it will make my code work?

Comment: I think this.name has nothing to do with image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some problems in the current implementation, I am posting the working code below. The first problem was that I was using JavaScript style calling for `onload` function. The second problem was I have to put all the code inside `onload` function because `readAsArrayBuffer` is an async call.

```
var fileByteArray = '';
const Image = this.AccUserImage.nativeElement;
if (Image.files && Image.files[0]) {
    this.AccUserImageFile = Image.files[0];
}
var fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = (e) => {
    var imageData = fileReader.result;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(imageData);
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        fileByteArray += (String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]));
    }

    this.name = Image.files[0].name;
    const ImageFile: File = this.AccUserImageFile;
    let length = this.form.value.addresses.length;
    this.testList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        testDetails.image = btoa(fileByteArray);
    }
}
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(Image.files[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the test should be at the end of the fileReader.load function because your test depends on fileReader.onload function to be finished at least once so fileByteArray is not undefined.

```
fileReader.onload = function (event) {
    var imageData = fileReader.result;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(imageData);
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        fileByteArray += (String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]));
    }
    if (fileReader && Image.files && Image.files.length) {
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(Image.files[0]);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      let testDetails = new testDto();
      testDetails.image = btoa(fileByteArray);
    }
};
```